# Error while calling method in Public Folder

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

We have a website and in it, we have a folder called 'Test'. In web.config we have allowed all access this folder as

```
  <location path="Test">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I created a new aspx page under this folder, lets say its called TestPage.aspx and i can call it without system throwing me back to Login page (webiste.com/Test/Testpage.aspx). On

> document.ready()

of TestPage.aspx, i make an ajax call to one of the methods on this page and it get error. On checking the result, i see that its returning the HTML of login page. I looks like i can access that page as a whole initially but when i try to call a method through ajax, its trying to authenticate me as a user.

Is their a way to accomplish what i am trying to achieve here? Accessing method through Ajax without user being authenticated.

Thanks

Comment: Some workarounds are shown here to suppress login redirect https://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx/